# Coprimes satisfying a pair

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, number-theory, primes

We know that number of coprimes less than a number can be found using [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).
But if there are two numbers $p$ and $q$ and we need to find number of numbers less than $q$ and coprime to $p$, is there any efficient method?

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that computing the Euler totient function provides an easy way to find out the number of coprimes less than a number. But that's the _definition_ of the function -- is there any known efficient way of actually computing it?

Comment: It involves computing the prime factorization of the number, which isn't known to be easy. Also, I've just noticed that the article you linked is just a rip-off of Wikipedia, so I've changed that to point to the original. Please don't encourage Wikipedia rip-offs.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This is as hard as factoring, and there is no known efficient algorithm for factoring.  In particular, there is a standard reduction to show that if you could compute Euler's totient function efficiently, then you could factor efficiently.